# Add columns to dynamic ng-table based on results of promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I've been using the `ngTableDynamic` directive recently and it works great when I know exactly what columns my table should expect. However, I'm running into issues when my table is truly dynamic and I do not know in advance the number or type of columns to expect.

At the top of my controller I declare the columns I know will be present in every table:

```
$scope.columns = [
  { title: 'ID', field: 'id', visible: true, required: true },
  { title: 'Email', field: 'email', visible: true, required: true }
];
```

I then make an asynchronous call to a service which returns results. Based on these results I push any additional column objects into `$scope.columns`:

```
var getResults = function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  reportService.getReportResults({
    report: $scope.id,
    version: $scope.version
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data.results;
    _.each($scope.data[0], function(value, key) {
      if (key !== 'id' && key !== 'email') {
        $scope.columns.push({
          title: _str.capitalize(key),
          field: key,
          visible: true,
          required: false
        });
      }
    });
    defer.resolve($scope.data);
  });
  return defer.promise;
};
```

However, the columns pushed within `_.each` never make it to my table when I view it in the browser. If I replace my asynchronous call with a hard-coded mock of an example set of data however, the columns are added and everything works as expected:

```
var getResults = function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  $scope.data = [{"id":"1","email":"test@sample.com",,"create_date":"2013-09-03T09:00:00.000Z"},{"id":"2","email":"sample@test.org","create_date":"2013-09-03T11:10:00.000Z"}];
  _.each($scope.data[0], function(value, key) {
    if (key !== 'id' && key !== 'email') {
      $scope.columns.push({
        title: _str.capitalize(key),
        field: key,
        visible: true,
        required: false
      });
    }
  });
  defer.resolve($scope.data);
  return defer.promise;
};
```

Further down in my controller my init code calls

```
getResults().then(function() {
  $scope.tableParams.reload();
});

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({...
```

My assumption is that as soon as the promise is resolved `$scope.tableParams.reload();` is called before `$scope.columns` is updated.

Comment: What happens to the hardcoded mock version if you move that `getResults().then(...` call to after you instantiate `$scope.tableParams`?

Comment: Hi, i'm not too proficient in Angular, but could you please tell me what `$promise` means here?

    
        `version: $scope.version
    }).$promise`

I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: @Mridul https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource, find $promise

Comment: @AsimKT i know about promises. i mean, i have never seen the usage like that. by chaining `$promise`. could you point me to an example maybe?

Comment: @Mridul You may not saw it, because most of the time we use $http for our API calls. $promise is with $resource, which gives the original promise object. Read the section on $promise which I shared. Example is also in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [demo](http://ng-table.com/#/columns/demo-visibility) from documentation it was quite is to make example with promises.
It just seems that you have to create new tableParams and cols object after getting response from promise. Adding rows to existing cols may not trigger watcher.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

angular.module('app').controller('Demo', function($scope, NgTableParams, dataService) {
  $scope.cols = [{
    title: 'ID',
    field: 'id',
    visible: true
  }, {
    title: 'Email',
    field: 'email',
    visible: true
  }, {
    title: 'Create Date',
    field: 'create_date',
    visible: true
  }];
  
  dataService
    .getData()
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        dataset: response.results
      });
      $scope.cols = $scope.cols.concat(response.cols);
    });
});

angular.module('app').factory('dataService', function($timeout) {
  return {
    getData: function() {
      return $timeout(function() {
        var n = Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 5;
        var results = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          results.push({
            id: Math.random(),
            email: 'ex' + Math.random() + '@example.com',
            create_date: new Date(),
            x: Math.round(Math.random() * 10),
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * 25)
          });
        }

        return {
          results: results,
          cols: [
            {
              title: 'X',
              field: 'x',
              visible: true
            },
            {
              title: 'Y',
              field: 'y',
              visible: true
            }
          ]
        };
      }, 500);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Demo">
  <table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{row[col.field]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you apply your data to the $scope asynchronously (in the promise then block) so you are outside the angular digest cycle, and your table won't update.

This doesn't happen in your mock because you set $scope.data synchronously.
( [A more detailed explanation can be found here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) )

To fix this, you should notify angular that you've made some changes to the scope with $scope.$digest()

I see some other issues with your code, which I'll try to address

- bad usage of promises (read: avoid 'defer' whenever you can)
- no functional approach
- a little confusion about promises/angular in general

Enough chatter, this is how I'd write your same function:

```
var getResults = function() {

    // fetch data
    return reportService.getReportResults( {
            report: $scope.id,
            version: $scope.version
        } )
        .then( function( data ) {

            // assign the values
            $scope.data = data.results

            // notify angular to recheck his array
            $scope.$digest()

            // consider using a functional approach to have a cleaner code
            _( $scope.data )
                .first()
                .keys()
                .filter( key => ( key !== 'id' && key !== 'email' ) )
                .each( key => {
                    $scope.columns.push( {
                        title: _str.capitalize( key ),
                        field: key,
                        visible: true,
                        required: false
                    } )
                } )
                .value()

            return $scope.data
        } )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as

```
var getResults = function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  reportService.getReportResults({
    report: $scope.id,
    version: $scope.version
  }).$promise.then(defer.resolve);
  return defer.promise;
};


 getResults().then(function(_data) {
 $scope.data = _data;
 _.each($scope.data, function(value, key) {
      if (key !== 'id' && key !== 'email') {
        $scope.columns.push({
          title: _str.capitalize(key),
          field: key,
          visible: true,
          required: false
        });
      }
    });

 });
```

or directly in controller as

```
    reportService.getReportResults({
    report: $scope.id,
    version: $scope.version
  }).then(function(_data) {
     $scope.data = _data;
     _.each($scope.data, function(value, key) {
          if (key !== 'id' && key !== 'email') {
            $scope.columns.push({
              title: _str.capitalize(key),
              field: key,
              visible: true,
              required: false
            });
          }
        });

     });
```